# Template Class Static Data Instantiation?

Tags: c++

Any one can tell me what on earth is going on in this code?

```
#include <iostream>

class BBB {

    public:

    BBB() { std::cout << std::endl << "BBB()" << std::endl; }

    ~BBB() { std::cout << std::endl << "~BBB()" << std::endl; }

};

template<class T> 
class AAA {

    public:

    AAA(){}
   ~AAA(){}

   void foo() {}

   private:

   static BBB b;
};

template<class T>
BBB AAA<T>::b;

//class CCC {
//
//private:
//    
//    static BBB bb;
//
//};
//
//BBB CCC::bb;

AAA<int> a;

int main()
{
    //AAA<int> a;
    a.foo();

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that the constructor of "b" object in AAA is not called when the containing class is template.   Try uncomment the CCC class definition and the "bb" object constructor will be called.  This is strange since the template class A is instantiated.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried both Visual C++ 2008 and GCC 4.5, t behaves the same under both compilers.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, each member of a class template is instantiated only if that particular member is used.  Since your code never uses member `AAA<int>::b`, that member is not instantiated.

Adding the no-operation statement `b;` to `AAA<T>::AAA()` or `AAA<T>::~AAA()` or `AAA<T>::foo()` causes the `AAA<int>::b` static object to be constructed and destructed as you expected.

Or, if you want to tell the compiler to go ahead and instantiate all members of a certain class template specialization, use an explicit instantiation (in a source file, not header):

```
template class AAA<int>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Templates are different than other kinds of classes in that only what is used is ever instantiated.  Since you never actually USE the BBB inside of A, it is never created.

Comment: ic ic, then is this stated in the specification?  If it's compiler dependent then it's disastrous since I need this feature form my pool-based custom STL allocator.

Comment: It's standard behavior.  So long as you use the variable at some point, it'll be instantiated correctly.  If your program never accesses it though it won't be.